# Ошибка с LEFT JOIN после условия WHERE ILIKE

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, pgadmin4

Столкнулся с проблемой с условием WHERE ILIKE.
Решил проверить SQL запрос с условиями, но встретил ошибку и не понимаю как её исправить. В общем имею это:

```
LEFT JOIN public."Post" AS "Post" ON "Contact"."PostId" = "Post"."PostId" WHERE "Post"."DisplayName" ILIKE 'оператор машины'
LEFT JOIN public."ContactPhone" AS "ContactPhone" ON "Contact"."ContactId" = "ContactPhone"."ContactId"
```

Это только честь из всех JOINов, но ошибка заключается в этом:

```
ERROR syntax error at or near "LEFT"
```

И она возникает после условия WHERE ILIKE. Как можно обойти её?

Comment: Это что за огрызки? выкладывайте ПОЛНЫЙ текст запроса. И отформатируйте его нормально..

Comment: @Akina Там только JOINы и простой SELECT FROM. В данный момент я с телефона и не могу это сделать.

Comment: @Akina ошибка появилась только после условия WHERE ILIKE. Без неё ошибки нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сразу после `JOIN` может идти условие только в виде `ON`. А `WHERE` должно быть в самом конце, после всех `JOIN`, одно на весь `SELECT`.

Т.е. скорее всего тут нужно просто написать через `AND` в `ON` условие, поскольку оно относится именно к присоединяемой таблице:

```sql
LEFT JOIN public."Post" AS "Post" 
    ON "Contact"."PostId" = "Post"."PostId" AND "Post"."DisplayName" LIKE 'оператор машины'
LEFT JOIN public."ContactPhone" AS "ContactPhone" 
    ON "Contact"."ContactId" = "ContactPhone"."ContactId"
```

В общем случае можно писать и так, добавив нужные условия в самом конце через `WHERE`:

```sql
LEFT JOIN public."Post" AS "Post" ON "Contact"."PostId" = "Post"."PostId" 
LEFT JOIN public."ContactPhone" AS "ContactPhone" ON "Contact"."ContactId" = "ContactPhone"."ContactId"
WHERE "Post"."DisplayName" LIKE 'оператор машины'
```

Comment: Спасибо. Условие WHERE ILIKE убрал в конец и всё заработало. Спасибо:)

Comment: @AlexanderDegurechaff Ну, можно и так и так, как оптимальнее не знаю, с одной стороны "сложные" условия (не на равенство каких-то `id`) наверное красивее писать в `WHERE` в конце, а с другой стороны вроде бы это условие на присоединяемую таблицу и поэтому оно просится в `ON` )  Опять же, наверное, лучше в `ON` писать те условия, на которые есть индекс в таблице